# Is there a way to make a VIEW statement in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I had a table named table1 and have a three column.. column1, column2,column3..
I want to view the value of my columns in table using VIEW statement not SELECT is it possible?
Thank in advance@

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "view". In "SQL-ish", a [View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29) is "the result set of a stored query"... so, specifically, in Access parlance, a View is a query object, and that is, of course, a `select` statement.

Answer (score 2):

No.  **View** is a SQL database concept.  You will have to use **SELECT...** to create a query, which is essentially the same thing.  MSAccess has no concept of **Views**, it uses **Queries**.

Answer (score 2):

A *view* is an SQL query that has been given a name and stored in the database. That is exactly what the Access *queries* are.